# QtCreator GDB not finding correct shared library

Tags: c++, gdb, qt-creator

I have a docker image which I am using to build a project. That project generates several executables and .so libraries.

I am able to GDB debug on the command line with the proper LD_LIBRARY_PATH set, and it finds the libraries correctly and I am able to step debug into those .so files.

I am trying to use QtCreator "Start and debug external application" to gdb debug this application.

In QtCreator, I am using the set solib-search-path command in the "Additional Startup Commands" of the Debugger->GDB tab , and in the QtCreator debug log I see it being set:

```
set solib-search-path /home/me/mypath/dist.x86/Linux5.4_x86_64_cc_glibc_PTH_64_DBG.OBJ/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib64
```

However, when the program runs, the executable is not finding the correct version of the shared library.

Is there something else I need to do to make this work? Do I need to launch QtCreator from an environment where LD_LIBRARY_PATH has already been set? I have verified with ldd the executables and shared libraries have the path I am using for solib-search-path once I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH when I am using command line GDB to debug.

Comment: Can't you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in `Projects / Build & Run / Run / Run Environment`?

Comment: The problem is, I am not running at QT Project, just trying to use the GUI debugger for an external project.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you can debug in QtCreator without a project.

Comment: Yes - it is my preferred C debugger actually..if you can get it set up right. I ended up just doing what I said - launching QtCreator with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set from the command line and it picked up the library..not sure why it wasn't working with the solib-search-path in GDB

Comment: So, do you use `Start and Debug External Application` when debugging without a project? In that case you have to select a specific Kit. Have you tried changing the environment in the Kit?